# avfoundation front camera retina flash overexposed

Tags: ios, image-processing, camera, avfoundation, photo

I am using AVFoundation to capture photo in my app. Everything works fine until i use retina flash in the dark. Photos are too exposed. Face looks like a light bulb. And I am using Auto exposure and whitebalance settings. Anyone has any solutions for it?
Thanks!

Comment: Show some basic/small testable code to recreate your issue. You'll get faster answers that way. Did you try **not using** auto-exposure but instead use own settings for in the dark photos?

Comment: I am doing it for non retina devices but when applying manual settings on retina devices behaviour is very inconsistent, sometimes photos are almost normal in same light conditions and sometimes they are too bright but one thing which is consistent is - Lock yourself in a totally dark room and use AVFoundation all auto mode to capture photo using retina flash, face will shine like a light bulb.